# SelectedIndex en tabla dinámica

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo el siguiente código, el cual es un select en una tabla dinámica. El SelectedIndex me funciona únicamente en la primera fila, en el resto no. Deseo saber dónde está el error. Gracias

```js
$(document).on('change','select[name="acciones"]',function() {
document.getElementsByName("acciones")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
var link = $(this).find(':selected').attr('href'); //La variable link toma el valor que se selecciona del select y lo reemplaza por el link, que va a ser el contenido que saldra en el colorbox
var link2 = $(this).find(':selected').attr('class'); //La variable link2 toma el valor que se selecciona del select y lo reemplaza por la clase
if (link2 == "observaciones" || link2 == "fechas") {//en caso de que la clase sea observaciones, correos o fechas, hará la condicion if 
$.colorbox({iframe: true, width: "450px", height: "300px", scrolling: true, transition: "fade", href: link,
onOpen: function () {
$('body').css({'overflow-y': 'hidden'});
},
onClosed: function () {
$('body').css({'overflow-y': 'auto'});
}});//funcion colorbox. El href va a ser la del select, utilizando la variable link
} else {
$.colorbox({iframe: true, width: "70%", height: "98%", scrolling: true, transition: "fade", href: link,
onOpen: function () {
$('body').css({'overflow-y': 'hidden'});
},
onClosed: function () {
 $('body').css({'overflow-y': 'auto'});   
}});} ;})
```

Comment: y la tabla? deberías poner todo el código que afecta al problema para que te podamos ayudar.

Comment: @FranIslas en sí lo que deseo es seleccionar n veces una misma opción y que el colorbox se siga abriendo. No se si haya un método más fácil